# Preventing tqdm from printing anything after error

Tags: python, tqdm

when handling errors in a tqdm loop, I'd like error messages to be the last thing printed. A MWE:

```
import tqdm
import sys

for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(10)):

    if i == 3:

        print('error')

        sys.exit(1)
```

When running this, tqdm still prints a progress bar after the "error" message. Is it possible to avoid this (so that "error" is the last thing shown)?

EDIT: I'm actually calling `sys.exit` from different external modules that know nothing of tqdm, and I don't want to have a global variable with the tqdm object. Maybe I'm asking for too much...

Cheers.

Comment: This looks like a very contrived example. Can you show a more realistic example? How you can best deal with errors depends on the actual control flow you are using.

Comment: I just added an EDIT: I'm actually doing that, but *sys.exit* is in a different module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
call `close()` and make sure `leave` is False.

See: https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#close

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!! Problem is in the above example everything occurs inside the same module (main here), but my "sys.exit()"s are ocurring in other modules (which known nothing of tqdm), and I don't like the idea o a *global* variable with the tqdm object...but it's probably the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a `tqdm` instance in a variable and update it manually.

```
progress_bar = tqdm(total=10)
for i in range(10):
    progress_bar.update()
    
    do_stuff()

    if i ==3:
        progress_bar.close()
        print('error')
        sys.exit(1)
```

You can use `tqdm.trange` as a context manager to remove the need to update manually, but still provide a way to close it. See https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#description-and-additional-stats

Note that if you break out of a context manager, it will run its 'finally' section and close the tqdm instance.

Comment: Thanks!! In my case `leave=False` is enough (my bad: I though `leave=False` was the default)